# Изменение свойств элементов List массива через метод в цикле foreach C#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Итак, есть список `List<Rectangle> rect_list = new List<Rectangle>();`, нужно в цикле изменить свойство `Location` для всех объектов, у меня долго не получалось, делал через все возможные циклы `foreach`:

---

Так

```
foreach (var T in rect_list)
{
  T.Offset(-50, 0);
}
```

И так

```
rect_list.ForEach(delegate (Rectangle offset)
{
  offset.Offset(-50, 0);
});
```

Проблема в том что свойства объектов не меняются вообще, как будто с ними ничего и не делают, проблему я решил так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rect_list.Count; i++)
{
  rect_list[i] = new Rectangle(rect_list[i].X -50, rect_list[i].Y, 50, 50);
}
```

Но хотелось бы сделать это через `foreach` это возможно сделать? или он годится только для вывода информации куда либо?

---

В общем вопрос такой, как сделать то что у меня сделано в цикле `for` через цикл `foreach`?

Comment: Можно оставить foreach, но надо сделать Rectangle классом. И именно это будет более правильно, потому что изменяемые структуры — зло. Если объект может меняться — все, сразу делаем его классом, примите как правило. Либо делайте структуру неизменяемой и вместо изменения создавайте новый экземпляр, но тогда это можно будет сделать также только в цикле for

Comment: Цикл `for` здесь норм. Он достаточно быстрый и не требует оптимизации. С другой стороны, быть может вы общую задачу решаете не оптимальным образом, потому что переписывание такого количества данных не выглядит, как нормальная операция. Возможно вам вообще цикл не нужен, но в контексте данного вопроса это не определить. Даже неизвестно, что за тип приложения.

Answer (score 3):

`Rectangle` является структурой. Особенность структур в том, что присваивания осуществляется через копирование. `foreach` разворачивается в такую структуру:

```
var e = rect_list.GetEnumerator();
while(e.MoveNext()) {
  Rectangle r = e.Current;
  ...
}
```

Соотвественно, все, что произойдет с r будет происходить с копией элемента.

Поэтому ответ на вопрос "как сделать то что у меня сделано в цикле for через цикл foreach" - никак.

Comment: Ну почему же, можно перед foreach объявить переменную типа ин-т, присвоить ей 0. И в foreach делать следующее: { rect_list[i++].Offset(-50, 0)} =)

Comment: Можно, конечно. Но лучше использовать for если уже делать через индекс.

Comment: а по каким симптомам вы определили, что Rectangle - структура, а не класс?

Comment: @Anatol, по симптомам, описанным в вопросе :)

Comment: @Anatol просто помню.

Comment: @AlexNetkachov пропущена часть вопроса, на мой взгляд, более важная (или как минимум - не менее важная), чем особенности структур. Свойства объектов **можно** менять при перечислении в `foreach`

Comment: @Anatol Свойства объектов можно менять. <- точка тут :-)

Comment: @AlexNetkachov ну вы же понели, ответ будет хрестоматийным, если копипастнуть сюда пару абзацев с доки про форич в части мутабельности/иммутабельности